# Written warning given to me for something that someone else in a very similar position got away with completely, help!

Tags: management, colleagues, complaint

So I was handed a written warning for my alleged conduct with a colleague. It was claimed that I had sworn during a discussion with a nurse. BTW didn't. The colleague put in a complaint and got her 2 friends that were also there to back up her story. I was put through an investigation and came out with a written warning. Now, a colleague has been seen and heard by senior members of staff (including the deputy manager) to have sworn loudly and clearly and often during an argument with a colleague. Nothing has been brought against her and she has completely gotten away with it.

Am I in any position to show that preferential treatment was shown to my colleague and that I myself should not have been handed a written warning when others have done the exact same thing and gotten away with it?

How would I go about appealing the decision of the written warning?

Comment: If your company has written warnings it also has procedures for appealing them. You know your company better than we do; so I don't see how we can help you go about appealing it...

Comment: So they got away with swearing while you didn't. Oh wait, you didn't swear at all. Hmm. You don't sound like a very reliable witness.

Answer (score 10):

How do you know that nothing has been done?   How do you know that she got away with it?

Keep in mind that disciplinary actions are completely private in well-run organizations.  You should not - and should not expect to - have any insight into any sort of corrective action against a fellow employee.  For all you know, your co-worker could have gotten the exact same written warning.  Or something more severe.  Or something less severe.  It's really none of your business, and you will likely be told so if you try to bring it up to improve your own circumstances.

Your best approach is to handle your own situation and ignore your co-worker's.  If you feel that you were wrongly accused, by all means contest the situation, but let your case stand on its own merits.  Apply appropriate evidence and reasoning based upon YOUR circumstances.  There's no need to bring the other person's situation into it.